# VSC vs PyCharm auto-completion tab : can it fill function, parenthesis and exit the line?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've been using so far PyCharm to code Python. I've recently been introduced to Visual Studio Code, as it seems lighter and faster and that my computer is old, I'm thinking to move to VSC for all my coding.

There is something however that I found very convenient with PyCharm with auto-completion :
when you start to write a function/class/method... it offers really quickly some suggestion (auto-completion), and by pressing tab it completes the let's say function, adding the brackets/parenthesis. Then it sets the cursor in the parenthesis. Another press on the TAB then it will take you out of the parenthesis.

I've found how to auto-complete functions with VSC, but after the first TAB press, bringing me inside functions parenthesis, another hit on TAB will instead bring me another suggestion.

Is there a way to get VSC using auto-tab-completion same to PyCharm? (and BTW, how about in Sublime?)

Comment: While you can re-configure a lot in Visual Studio Code it should be clear that it is not going to be PyCharm. You will not get the same IDE that just used less resources. So, my personal advice: get used to the differences or stay with PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it's impossible for now.

What you have taken in the PyCharm was `Jump Outside Current Bracket/Quote` command, but it's not available in the VSCode.

VSCode only provides the command of `editor.action.jumpToBracket` and `editor.action.selectToBracket`, both of them were not what you are looking for.

But if you don't like it jump to next suggestion, you can move the keybinding of it like this:

[image]

Comment: That seems to be right. I like this jump in and out of Pycharm! And thanks for the suggestion to change the key binding. I had to look it up to find where to actually find this : File -> Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts then insert "tab" in the searchbar.